# Submit form after hover for 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I am trying to figure out how to set a time, when the user hovers over the submit button, after which the form will be submit (2 seconds).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit95").hover(function(){
    var form95 = $("#form_sub_category_id95");
    $("#form_sub_category_id95").ajaxSubmit({
      target: "#output110",
      data: form95.serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        $("#product_default110").hide();
        $("#output110").html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: mouseover: `setTimeout()` / mouseleave: `clearTimeout()`  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit95").hover(function(){ 
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
        var form95 = $("#form_sub_category_id95");
        $("#form_sub_category_id95").ajaxSubmit( {
           target: "#output110", 
           data: form95.serialize(),
           success: function (data) {
                    $("#product_default110").hide();
                    $("#output110").html(data);     
                }
        });
        },2000);
    },function(){
        clearTimeout(timer); //when mouseout stop 
    });
});
```

Comment: Great solution, the only one so far that clears the timeout if the mouse leaves the button before the two seconds have elapsed. You should, however, declare the `timer` var at the top. Otherwise, it will be resolved on `window`, possibly leading to namespace conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeOut()` for that:

> The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

Write this code into another function

```
function callAfterSomeTime() {
  var form95 = $("#form_sub_category_id95");
  $("#form_sub_category_id95").ajaxSubmit({
    target: "#output110",
    data: form95.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      $("#product_default110").hide();
      $("#output110").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit95").hover(function(){ 
            setTimeout(function(){
            var form95 = $("#form_sub_category_id95");
            $("#form_sub_category_id95").ajaxSubmit( {
               target: "#output110", 
               data: form95.serialize(),
               success: function (data) {
                        $("#product_default110").hide();
                        $("#output110").html(data);     
                    }
            });
            },2000);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit95").hover(function() {
    setTimeout(doSubmit, 2000);
  }
);

function doSubmit() {
  var form95 = $("#form_sub_category_id95");
  $("#form_sub_category_id95").ajaxSubmit( {
     target: "#output110", 
     data: form95.serialize(),
     success: function (data) {
              $("#product_default110").hide();
              $("#output110").html(data);     
          }
     });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delay the submit with timeout and cancel it on mouseleave:

```
$('form').hover(function(){
     $(this).data('t', setTimeout(submitFn, 2000));
}, function(){
     clearTimeout($(this).data('t'));
});
```